# Checking for relationships between related models?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Assume `A` and `B` models are related to each others using Eloquent relations.

How should I check if an instance from A has relation with an instance from B?

For example in `A hasMany B` and `A belongsToMany B` situations I want to check if `$a` has relationship with `$b`.

I think I can check for this by accessing the relation object `$a->relatedBs()` but I don't know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been PR to the framework exactly for this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4267

```
$b = B::find($id);

$as = A::hasIn('relationB', $b)->get();
```

However Taylor didn't merge it, so you need `whereHas`:

```
// to get all As related to B with some value
$as = A::whereHas('relationB', function ($q) use ($someValue) {
   $q->where('someColumn', $someValue);
})->get();

// to check if $a is related to $b
$a->relationB()->where('b_table.id', $b->getKey())->first(); // model if found or null

// or for other tha m-m relations:
$a->relationB()->find($b->getKey()); // same as above

// or something more verbose:
$a->relationB()->where('b_table.id', $b->getKey())->exists(); // bool
```

Answer (score 0):

`A::has('B')->get();`

As shown in the laravel docs: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations

Comment: Tnx, but I dont want to get the instances from `A` that has relations with instances of `B`. Please check the question again.